# Passing variables to a function using a button and submitting via ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am attempting to setup a multiple select box page that has 1 master select box and a dynamic number of child ones.

For example:
I have 10 territories and within those 10 territories can be 100 counties.  I am using jquery to with buttons "Add" and "Remove" to move these counties between the different selector boxes.

Now the challange is to create javascript to submit the changes via ajax.
I know I am doing this the hard way right now by making the javascript dynamic with PHP so I am wondering a more simple way, as well as how I can pass those variables into the data string.

Right now I am using this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function() {
<?
$territories = $db->get_results("SELECT * FROM tbl_territories");
foreach ($territories as $territory) {
    echo "
    $('#remove-{$territory->id}').click(function() {
        return !$('#territory-{$territory->id} option:selected').remove().appendTo('#county');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'add.territoryselect.php',
            data: {
                action: 'remove',
                county: $(button).siblings('[name=/"ClientId/"]').attr(/"id/"),
            success: function(msg){
                alert( 'Data Saved: ' + msg );
            }
        });
    });
    $('#add-{$territory->id}').click(function() {
        return !$('#county option:selected').remove().appendTo('#territory-{$territory->id}');
    });";
}
?>
});
</script>
```

The page looks like this:

```
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <?
        foreach ($territories as $territory) {
        echo "
        <tr valign='middle'>
            <td align='center'>
                <a href='#'>{$territory->name}</a><br>

            </td>
            <td align='center'><label for='county'></label>
                <select style='width: 200px;' name='territory-{$territory->id}' size='5' multiple='multiple' id='territory-{$territory->id}'>";
                foreach ($counties as $county) {
                    if ($county->territory == $territory->id) {
                        echo "<option value='{$county->id}'>{$county->county}, {$county->state}</option>";
                    }
                }
                echo "</select>
            </td>
  <td align='center'><input type='submit' class='button green size-120 fl' value='&lt;&lt; Add' id='add-{$territory->id}'/><br /><br />
                        <input type='submit' class='button fl size-120' value='Remove &gt;&gt;' id='remove-{$territory->id}' />
      </td>
</tr>";
        }
        ?>
          </table></td>
        <td align="center" valign="top"><select style="width: 200px;" name='county' size='50' multiple='multiple' id='county'>
            <?
                foreach ($counties as $county) {
                    if (is_null($county->territory)) {
                        echo "<option value='{$county->id}'>{$county->county}, {$county->state}</option>";
                    }
                }
                ?>
          </select></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Obviously this page is not working right now as the ajax section is incomkplete as I am sure there is a better way to do this but my jquery/javascript knowledge is lacking.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: "Oh my god Becky, look at his code".. you need to get organized

Comment: Just trying to make it work before I clean it up any :)
The select boxes work and are passing the info along, just can't figure out the ajax function and how to pass the values through it.

Answer (score 1):

```
/"
```

should be

```
\"
```

Also you can use another syntax:

```
echo <<< EOD

your js here

EOD;
```

Or better you should use a template engine

Comment: And of course with template engine i just mean to separate bussiness from logic in this case

Comment: I get what you meant, more or less a statement like that makes people think, "Oh I need to go use SMARTY because it is a template engine". When PHP can handle it just fine without a 3rd party application. Not that my initial statement was any better.

Comment: before using a template engine, it would be better to use the MVC pattern, if not, a template engine would just complicate more the code (in my opinion)